# Isn't it time the aviation sector improve its policies

Tags: accidents

In spite of the strict rules and regulations we see many disasters taking place. Mostly the disaster occurs due to the lapse of one small policy or nature. If the policy is the best then why do crashes still take place.

If one jet meets a disaster only then other's follow suite regarding their policies(modification or updating it). Is it necessary for a plane to crash for the improvement of the aviation sector can't we hope for a zero crash year.

At first it's the MH series crashing and now recently one more from Algeria bound plane and later a training helicopter.

This year the aviation sector has made several people to think twice before they travel or they might end up in tragedy

Comment: let me put it this way: how often do planes crash? How often do buses crash?

Comment: @JanDvorak its like comparing prop engine with a jet, Do you get chances of survival mid air or on the ground

Comment: it's rarely just one thing that fails but a sequence of events that cooperate into a crash

Comment: @user285oo6 Planes-vs-Buses is a perfectly apt comparison: We kill *many more people* per passenger-mile on the roads than we do in the air every year, yet people don't "think twice" before getting in their car every morning to drive to work. Does the automobile/driving "industry" need to improve its policies to address their fatal accident rate?

Comment: "At first it's the MH series crashing" - [not the first fatal accident this year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_incidents_involving_commercial_aircraft#2014). "can't we hope for a zero crash year" - [we had one already, 1932](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_incidents_involving_commercial_aircraft).

Comment: @AakashM So you are agreeing that aviation is not safe anymore by saying only 1932 the year of 0 crash(not near 2000 atleast) and  for the MH which crashed in Inidian ocean we didn't get the Black box till now to avoid this in future.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, it's not as simple as 'safe' versus 'not safe' ?

Comment: @user285oo6 Can you name the year where we had 'zero' kills on roads? That would most likely be the years before cars were invented...

Comment: @SentryRaven more likely the years before *roads* were invented.

Answer (score 10):

> **In spite of the strict rules and regulations we see many disasters taking place.**

Do we?

In the last month or so we've seen several major aircraft accidents/incidents worldwide resulting in loss of hundreds of lives.

However in that same time we've probably seen tens or hundreds of thousands die from other accidental causes. For example in one small typical western country there are [17,000 accidental deaths each year](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/oct/28/mortality-statistics-causes-death-england-wales-2010) 2,000 deaths from transport accidents and 140,000 deaths from cancer.

```
 - Cancer                     140000
 - Transport Accidents          2000
 - Air accidents                  20
```

[[image] W.H.O.](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs310/en/)
<sup>Look, road injury: 1.3 million deaths each year.</sup>

In a rational society, this should have some weight in guiding where we ask our governments to spend our money and resources.

> **Is it necessary for a plane to crash for the improvement of the aviation sector**

Yes, to an extent. We the public only pay attention when these things are reported in the mass media, the rest of the time we demand cheap air fares and push out of business any airline that spends much more than the average on safety.

---

This isn't to argue that we should be complacent, in fact hundreds of people will spend months and years investigating each of those air accidents.